# Does the generator size matter in Diffie-Hellman?

Tags: key-exchange, diffie-hellman

For the [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) protocol I've heard that the [generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) 3 is as safe as any other generator. Yet, 32-bit or 256-bit exponents are sometimes used as generators.  What is the benefit of using these very large generators if they are just as safe as the generator 3?

If 3 is not the safest generator, how could one calculate the shortest length generator that would be considered secure?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The security of Diffie-Hellman depends upon the group in which DH is used, but not upon which generator is used *for this group*. See note 3.53 (chapter 3, page 103) of the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/).

In more details: for DH, we use a subgroup of size $q$ of the integers modulo $p$ (a big prime) with the multiplication as group operation. $q$ should be a prime of length at least $2n$ bits for a $2^n$ security level (or, at least, $q$ should have a prime divisor of at least $2n$ bits). Typical parameter sizes are 160 bits for $q$ and 1024 bits for $p$, or 256 bits for $q$ and 2048 bits for $p$. The generator $g$ is an element of order $q$.

When $p$ is a "safe prime", this means that $\frac{(p-1)}{2}$ is also prime. We then define $q = \frac{(p-1)}{2}$. In that situation, the order of any non-zero $g \bmod p$ (except 1 and $p-1$) is either $q$ or $2q$, hence every $g$ between $2$ and $p-2$ (inclusive) is a fine DH generator and ensures optimal security. Therefore it is customary to select a $g$ which makes computations easier, usually $g = 2$ or $g = 3$.

Another way to define a DH group is inherited from what is done with [DSS](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf) (a signature algorithm which also works in that kind of group): we first select a prime $q$ of appropriate size (e.g. 160 bits), then we look for $p$ by setting $p = qr+1$ for random values of $r$ of the right size (so that $p$ has the size we need), until we hit a prime $p$. This allows the use of a smaller $q$, thus smaller DH exponents and faster computations; on the other hand, we cannot choose the generator as freely in that case, because there are only $q-1$ generators of a subgroup of order $q$ modulo $p$. So we take a random value $s$ and compute $g = s^{(p-1)/q} \bmod p$. This yields an appropriate generator, but not a small one such as $2$ or $3$.

*Why wouldn't everyone use the obvious $2$ or $3$ rather than 256-bit numbers?*

A modular exponentiation uses a "square and multiply" algorithm. Using $2$ as generator simplifies the multiplies, but not the squarings, which represent the wide majority of the computation (especially when using window-based optimizations). Using $g=2$ is neat but does not imply that much of a performance enhancement.

Window-based optimization groups multiplications. Basically, you precompute $g^2, g^3 \dots g^{15}$; then, you do the squarings and you multiply with one of the precomputed values only once every four squarings. This is with a 4-bit window, you can have bigger windows; there are possible savings on the window building too. This is why the squarings use more than $\frac{2}{3}$ of the total CPU cost, closer to 80 or 85%. This leaves relatively little to optimize with $g=2$.

Most probably, someone had at some point a fuzzy feeling of a 256-bit number being "more secure" in some unspecified way. I have not seen that personally. Several protocols (e.g. [IKE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange), used for [IPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec)) use the "Oakley groups" from [RFC 2412 (Appendix E)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2412#page-45) which have $g=2$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying using 2 for the generator is no less safe, in which case I can simply shift left for the exponential operation.  It sounds too good to be true - is it?

Comment: @Thomas, Doesn't using g=2 (instead of making g a full-size group element) reduce the cost of an exponentiation operation from x to about 2x/3, i.e., a 33% reduction in time to exponentiate?  (Because about 2x/3 of the time x is taken on squarings, and x/3 is taken on multiplies; when you make g=2, the time for the multiplies goes to approximately zero.)  Or am I confused?

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas!  Very helpful.  (@jnm2: probably historical inertia, the defaults, lack of knowledge, and/or performance just doesn't matter enough for anyone to worry about it; I see this a lot in crypto.)