# Diffie-Hellman exchange result is always 1

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman, prime-numbers

I watched a [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modern-crypt/v/diffie-hellman-key-exchange-part-2) on Khan Academy explaining the Diffie-Hellman key exchange. When I try to do an example problem, I get 1 all the time. Does the generator and prime modulus (or base on Wikipedia) have to somehow be related for the key exchange to work?

Here is my example:

```
Generator: 47
Prime modulus: 23
Alice's private number: 6
Bob's private number: 19

Alice's public number: 47^6 mod23 = 1 
Bob's public number: 47^19 mod23 = 1

Shared number: 1^6 mod23 = 1
Shared number: 1^19 mod23 = 1
```

Comment: $47 \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$

Comment: Try a generator of 5.

Comment: @J.D. 5 works. Why does 5 work and 47 doesn't?

Comment: @Jake : $47 \equiv 1\not\equiv 5 \pmod{23}$

Comment: @RickyDemer sorry for how uneducated I am on this but would you mind explaining to me what that means? How do you get 5 and how are the prime modulus and the generator related?

Comment: [That means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation) you'll get the same results as if you raised $1$ to the exponents. I get 5 from J.D.'s comment and your comment.

Comment: 1 raised to any power is always 1.  This fact holds regardless of the modulus.  47 is (2*23)+1, and thus is congruent to 1 mod 23.  So 47 raised to any power is 1 (mod 23).  5, on the other hand, generates the multiplicative group of integers modulo 23, which is to say that all the integers from 1 to 22 can be generated by raising 5 to successive powers and reducing mod 23.

Comment: @Jake Basically, 47 is not a generator modulo 23, but 5 is. It's not called "generator" for nothing, it must have special properties that make it, well, a generator. That's your problem. See Gille's answer below for details

Answer (score 4):

For a given prime $p$, there are many choices for the generator $g$, but $g$ cannot be completely arbitrary. As the name hints, $g$ is supposed to be a *generator* of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ (or at least a large subgroup, more on this later), that is, it must have the property that the set of its powers modulo $p$ $\{g^1 \bmod p, g^2 \bmod p, g^3 \bmod p, \ldots, g^{p-1} \bmod p\}$ is equal to the set of elements $\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$.

You happened to pick $g = 47 = 2 \times 23 + 1$, thus $g \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. The set of powers of $1$ is just $\{1\}$, so it's about as far from a generator as it gets (the only way this could be “worse” would be a number like $46 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ which is not in the multiplicative group at all).

With large prime numbers, there's no efficient way to find a primitive root directly, but it's easy to test whether a candidate $g$ is a generator if the factorization of $p-1$ is known. This is because if $g$ is not a generator, its order (the smallest number $k \ge 1$ such that $g^k=1$) will be a multiple of one of the prime factors of $p-1$. The [Wikipedia article on primitive roots modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) (“primitive root modulo $n$” is another way to say “generator of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$”) and some results on the proportion of candidates that are generators.

In fact, the $g$ parameter in Diffie-Hellman [does not have to be a generator of the whole group](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/828/for-diffie-hellman-must-g-be-a-generator) in order for the protocol to work, in the sense that Alice and Bob end up with the same shared key. In fact, even in your example with $g=1$, the protocol “works”, but it has no security. For security, what matters is that $g$ generates a “large” enough subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$, where “large” means that the order of $g$ (i.e. the smallest $k \ge 1$ such that $g^k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$) is a multiple of a large prime.

There are [several techniques for generating Diffie-Hellman parameters](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/820/how-does-one-calculate-a-primitive-root-for-diffie-hellman). Typically $p$ is chosen in such a way that a good generator can be chosen easily. [A small generator is prefered for a minor performance improvement](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/639/does-the-generator-size-matter-in-diffie-hellman). There are bad values of $g$ that can lead to practical attacks but it is [easy to avoid them](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10025/diffie-hellman-choosing-wrong-generator-g-parameter-and-its-implications-of-p). An additional subtlety is that [if the order of $g$ has a small prime factor](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12961/diffie-hellman-parameter-check-when-g-2-must-p-mod-24-11) (which is the case if $g$ generates the whole of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$, since its order $p-1$ is then a multiple of $2$), there is a practical attack to find one bit of the shared secret, so choosing $g$ such that its order is a large prime is recommended.

Usually, $p$ and $g$ are chosen long in advance; many protocols or applications use built-in constants for $p$ and $g$, or have just a few of them to span different key sizes. There's no need to vary $p$ or $g$ for security, they can be reused.

Comment: Actually, one can argue that $g$ should generate a large prime order subgroup, as using a generator for the entire group leaks information.

Comment: @poncho That's interesting. What information is leaked? How does it help that $g$ isn't a generator?

Comment: If the order of $g$ has a factor $q$, then the attacker can, given $g^x$, derive $x \bmod q$ in $O(\sqrt{q})$ work.  If the order of $g$ is a large prime, then observation doesn't leak anything.