# Diffie-Hellman what is the subgroup

Tags: diffie-hellman

I am trying to understand the safety precautions regarding the variables used in Diffie-Hellman and I was refered to this post answer [Does the generator size matter in Diffie-Hellman?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/639/does-the-generator-size-matter-in-diffie-hellman).

> In more details: for DH, we use a subgroup of size q of the integers modulo p (a big prime) with the multiplication as group operation. q should be a prime of length at least 2n bits for a 2n security level (or, at least, q should have a prime divisor of at least 2n bits). Typical parameter sizes are 160 bits for q and 1024 bits for p, or 256 bits for q and 2048 bits for p. The generator g is an element of order q.

What is meant by `for DH, we use a subgroup of size q of the integers modulo p` I assume the group is the potential congruences of $\mod p$, but what is the subgroup. Since the generator should be a primitive root of `p` doesn't that mean that the group is $[1,p-1]$? This leads me to believe that $ q = p-1$. However this makes no sense when considering the following sentence `q` should be a prime of length at least `2n` bits for a `2n` security level (or, at least, `q` should have a prime divisor of at least `2n` bits). I am not sure what the `n` variable symbolizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the generator should be a primitive root of `p`

Well, here's your misunderstanding; the generator $g$ needn't generate the entire group $\mathbb{Z}^*_p$; instead, it can generate a proper subgroup (and in most cases, we select such a subgroup).

Here's the issue, if $h$ is a factor of the size of the group generated by $g$, then given $g^x \bmod p$, we can compute $h \bmod n$ in $O(\sqrt h)$ time.  If $g$ generates the entire group, well, its size will be $p-1$, which always has a factor of 2 (assuming $p>2$), and so we'd be giving away $x \bmod 2$ for free.

In contrast, if the size of the subgroup is a large prime (which implies that it is not the entire group), then the above observation doesn't give the attacker any advantage; the only factors of the subgroup size are 1 (which doesn't tell the attacker anything) and the large subgroup size itself (which is too large to make $O(\sqrt{h})$ time feasible.

Comment: Thank you so much, if only I knew this yesterday!

Comment: How could $$x \mod 2$$ be used to compromise a secret value? If we have prime 761, and the generator as 6. Then our subgroup is of order 760. 
If we use $$6^5 \mod 761$$ how is $$5 \mod 2$$ going to give us any information about  ``5`` being the secret value?

Comment: @JonasGrønbek: from just $x \bmod 2$ against the size of modulii we use in practice, not much.  However, a) we generally prefer not leaking anything, and b) of $p-1$ has other small factors, that increases the leakage.

Comment: I don’t have the abstraction required to understand why “leakage” leakage is a problem. I really samt a concrete example where a leak can be used to compromising something